# angular cli installation error windows

Tags: windows, npm, angular-cli

I'm getting a weird error message in my Command prompt while trying to install angular-cli. I'm also running the CMD.exe as an administrator. The error message reads as follows:

```
     npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
     npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
     node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
     npm ERR! node v7.4.0
     npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5

     npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null
     npm ERR!
     npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
     npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

     npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
     npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
```

Additional Info:
Windows 7 64 bit,
node version 7.4.0, npm version 4.0.5,

Comment: Try to disable antivirus, check proxy settings. May be install stable version of node.

Comment: How should the proxy settings be configured?

Comment: I would also like an answer to this. This happens to me when downgrading on ubuntu